# Is this algorithm right and faster than Dijkstra's algorithm for directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

For the shortest path of directed graph, I got a solution:

1. Compute the indegree of every vertex, and then construct an array Indegree[NumVertex].
2. Beginning with the source point, update the Dist of adjacement vertices if the new computed Dist is smaller, and these vertices' indegree also minus 1.
3. Push the adjacement points which indegree equals 0 into the quene.
4. Then dequene one vertex, and deal with that vertex as above.
5. It will stop when the quene is empty.

This solution is similar to topological sort.

I have tried some test cases and got the correct results.

Is this algorithm correct?

Also this solution's time complexity is |E|+|V|.

Is it really faster than Dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: Topology sort only works on acyclic directed graphs because else it is not guaranteed to have an node without incoming edges. Have you tried your algorithm on a cyclic directed graph?

Comment: Thank you, I just test it on cyclic directed graph and it doesn't work. So, when I limit the solution only on acyclic directed graph,  is this solution right and faster?

Comment: Yes, shortest path in DAGs can be solved in linear time with an algorithm similar to what you've described.